# Sum values from multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012, I have a  table `my_table` that has columns `state, month, ID`, and `sales`.

My goal is to merge different rows that have the same `state, month, ID` into one row while summing the `sales` column of these selected rows into the merged row.

For example:

```
state    month    ID    sales
-------------------------------
FL       June     0001   12,000
FL       June     0001    6,000
FL       June     0001    3,000
FL       July     0001    6,000
FL       July     0001    4,000  
TX       January  0050    1,000
MI       April    0032    5,000
MI       April    0032    8,000
CA       April    0032    2,000
```

This what I am supposed to get

```
state    month    ID    sales
-------------------------------
FL       June     0001   21,000
FL       July     0001   10,000  
TX       January  0050    1,000
MI       April    0032   13,000
CA       April    0032    2,000
```

I did some research, and I found that the self join is supposed to do something similar to what I am supposed to get.

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) for `SUM()` has some clear examples

Answer (score 17):

Unless I am missing something in the requirements, why not just use an aggregate function with a `GROUP BY`:

```
select state, month, id, sum(sales) Total
from yourtable
group by state, month, id
order by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd49e/4)

The result is:

```
| STATE |   MONTH | ID | TOTAL |
--------------------------------
|    FL |    July |  1 | 10000 |
|    FL |    June |  1 | 21000 |
|    CA |   April | 32 |  2000 |
|    MI |   April | 32 | 13000 |
|    TX | January | 50 |  1000 |
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering there should be an index on column `id`, this query would be a better solution:

```
select state, month, id, sum(sales) Total
from yourtable
group by id, state, month
order by id
```