# SQL Server Sum multiple rows into one - no temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to see a most concise way to do what is outlined in this SO question: [Sum values from multiple rows into one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940397/sum-values-from-multiple-rows-into-one-row?rq=1)
that is, combine multiple rows while summing a column.

But how to then delete the duplicates.  In other words I have data like this:

```
Person  Value
--------------
1         10
1         20
2         15
```

And I want to sum the values for any duplicates (on the Person col) into a single row and get rid of the other duplicates on the Person value.  So my output would be:

```
Person  Value
-------------
1        30
2        15
```

And I would like to do this without using a temp table. I think that I'll need to use `OVER  PARTITION BY` but just not sure. Just trying to challenge myself in not doing it the temp table way. Working with SQL Server 2008 R2

Simply put, give me a concise stmt getting from my input to my output in the same table.  So if my table name is `People` if I do a `select * from People` on it before the operation that I am asking in this question I get the first set above and then when I do a `select * from People` after the operation, I get the second set of data above.

Comment: You mean `SELECT Person, SUM(Value) FROM YourTable GROUP BY Person` ? That would produce the result u described

Comment: If you want **"get rid of the other duplicates on the Person value"** then why 30 against Id 1?? Shouldn't it be 10 or 20??

Comment: I guess I have not made myself clear enough: I want to combine all rows that have the same Person value whilst summing the value.  Yes, @Yuriy sure that's the easy answer to get the result, now I want in the same stmt to just be left with the result in the same (source) table. (in other words your answer must show me how to update an existing record with the new value - or insert a new one - and then delete all the other records that have the same Person value.  Simply put, give me a concise stmt geting from my input to my output in the same table

Comment: I think the down vote is not warranted.  But I will clarify the challenging part

Comment: @PBMe_HikeIt: I have found the down-vote system here to be somewhat of an enigma.  If you look at my recent activity you will see were I commented on a question that got down-voted several times.  I pointed out that an almost identical question was asked by a user with a high reputation and that question was up-voted 40+ times.  So, I guess if you are not an established member ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why not using Temp table but here's one way to avoid it (tho imho this is an overkill):

```
UPDATE MyTable SET VALUE = (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM MyTable MT WHERE MT.Person = MyTable.Person);

WITH DUP_TABLE AS
   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY Person) As ROW_NO
    FROM MyTable)
DELETE FROM DUP_TABLE WHERE ROW_NO > 1;
```

First query updates *every* duplicate person to the summary value. Second query removes duplicate persons.

**Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db7aa/11**

Comment: thanks @Yuriy Galanter.  Yes, a bit artificial in not using temp but I wanted to see how it could be done

Answer (score 0):

All you're asking for is a simple `SUM()` aggregate function and a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Person, SUM(Value)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Person
```

The `SUM()` by itself would sum up the values in a column, but when you add a secondary column and `GROUP BY` it, SQL will show distinct values from the secondary column and perform the aggregate function by those distinct categories.

Comment: please see my comment above.  I need the stmt to make the changes in the source table