# Modify a SQL table to condense similar rows while summing up a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum, sql-update

Here is a question that is the general gist of what I am trying to do:

[Sum values from multiple rows into one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940397/sum-values-from-multiple-rows-into-one-row)

However, to my knowledge, I am seeking further functionality, which would permanently modify the table in question to look like the result of the SELECT statement that is being suggested in that other thread.

So the table:

```
Sales
--------------------------------------
account    product    qty    amount
--------------------------------------
01010      bottle     10     200
01010      bottle     20     100
01010      bottle     5      10
11111      can        50     200
11111      can        25     150
```

...would be permanently modified to look like this

```
Sales
--------------------------------------
account    product    qty    amount
--------------------------------------
01010      bottle     35     310
11111      can        75     350
```

As is answered in the link, using a SELECT with SUM and GROUP BY can show me what the table needs to look like, but how to I actually apply those changes to the *sales* table?

edit: This query will be run every time a new batch of sales is added into the system. It's intended to clean up the *sales* table after new records have been added.

**Alternative approach**

New records in *sales* are inserted in from a different table using something like this:

```
"INSERT INTO sales
    SELECT account, product, qty, amount
    FROM new_sales;"
```

If there is a way to take care of the summation during that previous INSERT, instead of adding duplicate rows in the first place, that would also be acceptable. Keep in mind, this solution would still need to work for new records that don't have existing duplicate rows in *sales*.

**EDIT: for posterity**

General response seems to be that my initial approach is not possible-- short of creating a *temp_sales* table with a CREATE and SELECT, then purging *sales* completely, and then copying the contents of *temp_sales* into the cleared *sales* table, and truncating *temp_sales* for future use.

The accepted solution uses the "Alternative approach" that I had also alluded to.

Comment: Where are the inserts coming from php for example?

Comment: Inserts are being copied in from a different table in the database. My initial thought was to copy in the data and then sum and consolidate just on the destination table, as this would handle cases for sales with new 'accounts' or 'products' as well as summing 'qty' and 'amounts' sales with existing 'accounts' or 'products'.

I'm using C# to format and execute the queries. Hoping to use the most efficient queries as possible and only use C# calculations or controls when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Table named  new_sales implies that this table is periodically purged , is that the case? And how do you identify which records should be used from this table to insert/update to sales?

Comment: Yes, "new_sales" is purged after all of the information is recorded in "sales".. which is basically as soon as this wanted solution is finished executing. Every record in "new_sales" is brought over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming new_sales is truncated after sales has been updated and then starts to refill you could use insert..on duplicate key..update for example

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t,t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t
    -> (account varchar(5),    product varchar(20),    qty  int default 0,  amount int default 0);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t1
    -> (account varchar(5),    product varchar(20),    qty  int default 0,  amount int default 0);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> alter table t
    -> add unique key k1(account,product);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t1 values
    -> ('01010'  ,    'bottle'   ,  10   ,  200),
    -> ('01010'  ,    'bottle'   ,  20   ,  100),
    -> ('01010'  ,    'bottle'   ,  5    ,  10),
    -> ('11111'  ,    'can'      ,  50   ,  200),
    -> ('11111'  ,    'can'      ,  25   ,  150);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.28 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t
    -> select account,product,t1qty,t1amount
    -> from
    -> (
    -> select t1.account,t1.product,sum(t1.qty) t1qty,sum(t1.amount) t1amount from t1 group by t1.account,t1.product
    -> ) s
    -> on duplicate key
    -> update qty = t.qty + t1qty, amount = t.amount + t1amount;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table t1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.32 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t1 values
    -> ('01010'  ,    'bottle'   ,  10   ,  200),
    -> ('01011'  ,    'bottle'   ,  20   ,  100),
    -> ('01011'  ,    'bottle'   ,  5    ,  10),
    -> ('11111'  ,    'can'      ,  50   ,  200),
    -> ('11111'  ,    'can'      ,  25   ,  150);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t
    -> select account,product,t1qty,t1amount
    -> from
    -> (
    -> select t1.account,t1.product,sum(t1.qty) t1qty,sum(t1.amount) t1amount from t1 group by t1.account,t1.product
    -> ) s
    -> on duplicate key
    -> update qty = t.qty + t1qty, amount = t.amount + t1amount;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 2  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+---------+---------+------+--------+
| account | product | qty  | amount |
+---------+---------+------+--------+
| 01010   | bottle  |   45 |    510 |
| 11111   | can     |  150 |    700 |
| 01011   | bottle  |   25 |    110 |
+---------+---------+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
```

Comment: I think this is generally along the lines of what I need. Although I'm not sure the final values in 't' are reflective of the sums of what you inserted in 't1' just before. For instance, I would expect the "11111 | can | 150 | 700" line to read "11111 | can | 75 | 350" --- as those would be the proper totals from the previous values inserted into t1. It seems the values doubled after being added together, or were simply added twice.

Comment: Ah wait. I'm sorry. You have shown a series of these inserts to show the effects of repeated use. The final values are the result of multiple batches being brought from t1, yes?

Comment: I also have a table called "false_sales" that functions very much like "new_sales", except it contains records for sales that have been voided or refunded and therefore need to be removed from 'sales'.  This would mean subtracting 'false_sales' qty and amount values from those in 'sales', and removing the record from 'sales' altogether if they zero out. ---- would that be a small inverse modification to the above query? Or is that more of a completely different problem?

Comment: one way would be to union new_sales and false_sales (multiplying false sales qty and amount by -1),  deleting from sales would have to be a periodic, separate exercise.

Comment: Ah, yes, false_sales and new_sales act independently and usually won't have corresponding records. Separate exercise it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table from a select statement.

So you could do something like:

```
create table sales_sum as 
  select 
     account,
     product,
     sum(qty),
     sum(amount) 
   from 
     sales
   group by 
     account, 
     product
```

That creates a table with the right structure, and it'll insert the records that you want to have. Of course you can adapt the query or the table name.

Comment: So does that mean there is no way to apply the changes to the *sales* table itself? This query will be run every time a new batch of sales is added in to the system, and is intended to keep the *sales* table clean. Creating a new table every time is not practical for this purpose.

Comment: @Leviathan3  I would use two tables. Or, based on your description, what you really want is a "view". With that, when the sales table gets updated, your view (which looks just like a table when you use it) automatically gets updated. You can create a view instead of a table by running my query above, but use `create view sales_sum as ...` instead of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

This query does what a ETL tool can do but every you need to  run the entire script :

----------Old Table

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (
  [state] varchar(2),
  [month] varchar(7),
  [ID] int,
  [sales] int
)
;
INSERT INTO yourtable ([state], [month], [ID], [sales])
  VALUES ('FL', 'June', 0001, '12000'),
  ('FL', 'June', 0001, '6000'),
  ('FL', 'June', 0001, '3000'),
  ('FL', 'July', 0001, '6000'),
  ('FL', 'July', 0001, '4000'),
  ('TX', 'January', 0050, '1000'),
  ('MI', 'April', 0032, '5000'),
  ('MI', 'April', 0032, '8000'),
  ('CA', 'April', 0032, '2000');

SELECT
  state,
  month,
  id,
  SUM(sales) Total
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY state,
         month,
         id;

-----Creating new table from old table

CREATE TABLE yourtable1 (
  [state] varchar(2),
  [month] varchar(7),
  [ID] int,
  [sales] int
)
;

----Inserting aggregation logic

INSERT INTO yourtable1 (state, month, id, sales)
  SELECT
    state,
    month,
    id,
    SUM(sales)
  FROM yourtable
  GROUP BY state,
           month,
           id;
-----Fetching records

SELECT
  *
FROM yourtable1;
```